# Accessing a property through reflection returns a different value

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

Ok, as my original question seemed a bit ambiguous because I was asking for a general question about the C# language, but showing part of a particular example where I was having a problem with it, I'm going to try to rewrite so that it is clearer that my question is about the C# language, not about my particular problem.

I currently have a property (several, in fact) of a class, that return a different value depending on whether you access them directly by code, or using reflection. This is what happens when I access the property using the immediate console of VS:

```
> SelectedLine.QtyOutstanding
0

> var prop = SelectedLine.GetType().GetProperty("QtyOutstanding")
> prop.GetValue(SelectedLine)
8
```

Regardless of how the property is defined, what is the difference, in C#, between both ways of accessing the property? 
Shouldn't they both run exactly the same code in the setter/getter, if there is one?

(Considering that GetType() returns the same type as the variable is declared as)

Comment: How is QtyOutstanding defined?  Is it a field or a property?

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Obviously a property, as `GetProperty(...).GetValue(...)` returns something. Otherwise OP would get an NRE. My guess would be that some thread is changing the properties value.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian I've added a small example of how it is defined. As you can see, there is nothing special about it :/

Comment: @HimBromBeere That was my first thought (that something was changing the value of the property) but, no matter how many times I access the property, using reflection always returns the correct value, and accessing the property does not.

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]. There's something happening that you're not showing us, and it's hard to guess exactly what it is.

Comment: @CodeCaster I can guarantee you that I would create a minimal example if I could, but right now I haven't even managed that. Right now I'm just at the point I'm asking in this question: what could cause C# to treat both accesses to the property differently? (Really, I didn't even know that was possible). Hopefully that will either lead me to a solution, or to what I have to extract from the app to create a verifiable example (and a new more defined question).

Comment: Well, seems like a chicken-egg-problem. Without any example we can (if at all) only guess - whilst without any idea you can´t provide a meaningful example.

Comment: Do you hide the property of your base-class? Does it exist there as well? How is `SelectedLine` defined?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to produce this, maybe your case looks like that?

If your SelectedLine is accessible via interface, and your class has an explicite implementation of that, but also has a public property with the same name, this could lead to different results.
Example

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var SelectedLine = (ILine)new Line(8);
        Console.WriteLine(SelectedLine.QtyOutstanding); // 0
        var prop = SelectedLine.GetType().GetProperty("QtyOutstanding");
        Console.WriteLine(prop.GetValue(SelectedLine)); // 8
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


class Line : ILine
{
    public Line(int qtyOutstanding)
    {
        QtyOutstanding = qtyOutstanding;
    }

    public int QtyOutstanding { get; }

    int ILine.QtyOutstanding
    {
        get
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

interface ILine
{
    int QtyOutstanding { get; }
}
```

Comment: Not my case, but it certainly shows how that could be possible, which is certainly surprising :O

Comment: That's a pitty. Did you debuged it, or verified by logging if both ways call the getter of the property?

Comment: Not really surprising IMHO as you´re explicitely implementing the interface. This way you have to use the interface-member, which is done by retrieiving the interface-type: `typeof(ILine).GetProperty(...).GetValue(...)`. Good showcase anyway.

Comment: @Malior Your comment did ring a bell. There is no code in my getter/setters but, as you might see from the brief code I posted, I'm using Realm, and I think Realm is using Fody to add code to the getters/setters at compile time. I'm going to investigate that, because at least that is a lead I can follow. Thanks a lot!